# Building PCL with Kinfu

Tags: pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am installing Point Cloud Library (PCL), without installing ROS. Now, I would like to use the open source version of Kinect Fusion (http://pointclouds.org/news/2011/12/08/kinectfusion-open-source/). So, I downloaded the latest PCL source from https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl, and then followed the compilation and installation instructions at http://pointclouds.org/downloads/source.html.

But how do I now run the Kinect Fusion implementation? I cannot seem to find any reference to Kinfu in the build files. I notice that there is a directory at `/PCL/src/gpu/kinfu_large_scale`, but in `/PCL/build/gpu` there are just some cmake files, and a makefile.

Perhaps this is something to do with the configuration, where I have not indicated that I want Kinfu to be built? I remember that when I originally ran cmake, it told me that it could not find OpenNI, so could this be the issue? I do have OpenNI2, because my camera (ASUS Xtion) does not work with the original OpenNI), but will Kinfu build with this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215820/building-pcl-with-kinfu/) by [Karnivaurus](https://answers.ros.org/users/21659/karnivaurus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2015-08-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My apologies for not seeing this earlier but I wasn't working with ROS at all for a few years..

Looking back at my own notes, I think you are right about pcl-kinfu depending on OpenNI. From memory the OpenNI code is only necessary for capturing the data, and not the underlying algorithm, but unfortunately it is considered a core dependency by the build process. Many checkboxes only appear conditionally if certain libraries are found, therefore, if OpenNI isn't found, the kinfu-related checkboxes won't appear.

Here are my old notes if anyone finds them useful:

In CMake, make sure the following checkboxes are selected:

- BUILD_CUDA
- BUILD_GPU
- BUILD_apps
- BUILD_examples

Select Configuration Manager - the following Build checkboxes at a minimum are necessary for kinfu:

- pcl_core
- pcl_gpu_kinfu
- pcl_gpu_containers
- pcl_io
- pcl_io_ply
- pcl_kdtree
- pcl_visualization

---

Originally posted by [Stephen Vidas](https://answers.ros.org/users/3606/stephen-vidas/) with karma: 131 on 2016-02-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-04-13**:
I have selected all four BUILD options but where is the `Configuration Manager` you mentioned? #ubuntu1404 #armv7 #ccmake

**Comment by [Stephen Vidas](https://answers.ros.org/users/3606/stephen-vidas/) on 2016-04-13**:
I think I was using Visual Studio, in which the Configuration Manager gives you the option to select/deselect a subset of libraries to build. I think all of the available ones are selected by default so you probably don't have to worry about that step - although it can speed up the compile time.

**Comment by [jacksonkr_](https://answers.ros.org/users/21619/jacksonkr_/) on 2016-04-14**:
Ah, okay I thought yours might have been a situation like that. I'm on ubuntu / using a terminal program called `ccmake`. So far no luck building kinfu but I did found another project called [Kintinuous](https://github.com/mp3guy/Kintinuous) which must be based on kinfu's initial work.